# Is it considered bad programming practice to have a large number of overloaded class constructors?

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I'm making a calendar application in c++ and I'm making a great number of overloaded constructors for the appointment class depending on the information provided(e.g. if i have a start time for the event but no end time, and a location, but no attached contacts)

```
class Appointment {
    public:
    //overloaded Constructors
    Appointment();
    Appointment(Date);
    Appointment(Date,Date);
    Appointment(Date,Date,std::string);
    Appointment(Date,Date,std::string,std::string);
    Appointment(Date,Date,std::string,std::string,Contact);
```

etc. etc. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What about creating an object and setting its properties afterwards via getter/setters ? (or default ones if you support them)

Comment: It really depends on what these constructors do. If for example do the same job you could just use a simple constructor with default arguments and avoid code bloat.

Comment: I didn't know about default parameters, that should work nicely for what I want to do, thank you!

Comment: I generally use the constructor to do the minimum required to put the object into a valid state to prevent Undefined Behaviour. Everything else through the normal interface. Most rules have their exceptions though depending on the situation.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a perfect application for the [named parameter idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either:

- Create the object (a valid one) and set its properties afterwards via interface setters (since it seems an object can have a variable number of properties this seems like a good choice)
- Use default parameters, e.g.

  ```
  Appointment(Date=getDefaultDate(),
              Date=getDefaultDate(),
              std::string=getDefaultString(),
              std::string=getDefaultString(),
              Contact=getDefaultContact());
  ```

It really boils down to how you prefer to handle and initialize your objects.

**An important sidenote:** in large production codebases default parameters is a C++ feature often frowned upon because it might hinder readability and/or render debugging more difficult in particular scenarios (especially when something unwanted goes on and you didn't consider a default parameter being chosen, default parameters [are specified on the declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989505/1938163) and that might also "hides" a potential problem from the developers)

Comment: +1 for the downsides of default arguments. I hadn't really thought of that before.

Comment: @anthropomorphic I had to learn it the hard way :(

Comment: thank you so much, I think per your suggestion I'll find a way to do it with minimal default constructors, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is totally unnecessary. As pointed out Macro A , you can default construct the object and afterwards you can use setters for them.

One more thing when designing a software you should keep in mind the rule of complete and minimal i.e you should provide all facilities in a class avoiding duplication/redundancy.

Comment: Please promote my name to a template at least, not a macro :'(