# Function argument taking other argument as default value

Tags: c++, default-arguments

I want a function argument to take the value of an other argument as a default value.

My question is: Why am i not allowed to do that ?

```
void foo(int a, int b = a)
{

}
```

and is there an other way to do it than that ?

```
void foo(int a)
{
   foo(a,a);
}

void foo(int a, int b)
{

}
```

Comment: This link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989483/where-to-put-default-parameter-value-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Why am i not allowed to do that ?

Because the evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified, it's not guaranteed that `b` will be initialized with the value passed in as the argument of `a`.

From [$8.3.6/9 Default arguments
[dcl.fct.default]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#9):

> A default argument is evaluated each time the function is called with
>   no argument for the corresponding parameter. A parameter shall not
>   appear as a potentially-evaluated expression in a default argument.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> int a;
> int f(int a, int b = a);            // error: parameter a
>                                     // used as default argument
> ```

and

> 2. and is there an other way to do it than that ?

Using function overloading would be simple and fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
void foo(int a, int b = a) { ... }
```

is an error as per the standard.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **8.3.6 Default arguments**
>
> 9 Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in a default argument,
>   even if they are not evaluated. Parameters of a function declared before a default argument are in scope and can hide namespace and class member names. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> int a;
> int f(int a, int b = a); // error: parameter a
>                          // used as default argument
>
> ...
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*