# Function does not take X arguments, function with default arguments

Tags: c++, winsock, default-arguments

I have a function declaration

```
int checkWinsockError(int errorCode, const char *errorType, bool getError, int WSAAPI cleanupFunc(), struct addrinfo *addrToFree, SOCKET *socketToClose, bool sockError);
```

and a function definition.

```
int checkWinsockError(int errorCode, const char *errorType, bool getError=false, int WSAAPI cleanupFunc()=nullptr, struct addrinfo *addrToFree=nullptr, SOCKET *socketToClose=nullptr, bool sockError=false) {
      // error handling code
}
```

When I make a call to this function,

```
checkWinsockError(10000, "error");
```

I get the error ''checkWinsockError': function does not take 2 arguments'. This call to the function

```
checkWinsockError(10000, "error", false);
```

overriding the first default argument gives the error ''checkWinsockError': function does not take 3 arguments'. This continues until I override the last default argument, sockError, with a function call like this.

```
checkWinsockError(10000, "error", false, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, false);
```

I only began experiencing this error after adding sockError to the list of parameters. Why does the compiler force me to pass a value for this parameter when there is a default argument? I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the Winsock library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to put default parameter value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989483/where-to-put-default-parameter-value-in-c) TL;DR put default values in the declaration, not the definition.

Comment: @churill Yeah that fixes it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In the point of the function call the compiler sees only the declaration of the function that does not have default arguments.