# What is the value of the parameter

Tags: c++, qt

I am studying Drone Programming in C++. I found this function :

```
void Vehicle::_announceArmedChanged(bool armed)
```

But when I search for it, all the code calls this function without a parameter, such as:

```
connect(this, &Vehicle::armedChanged, this, &Vehicle::_announceArmedChanged);
```

In this case, where does the program get the `armed` status?

Comment: you might be looking at the definition while the declaration might declare a default parameter. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989483/where-to-put-default-parameter-value-in-c

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `connect` takes a member function as parameter ;)

Comment: wait a sec... `connect(this, &Vehicle::armedChanged, this, &Vehicle::_announceArmedChanged);` does not call the function. It passes a function pointer to `connect` the function is called elsewhere

Comment: That looks like a Qt signal/slot connection, which indeed just creates a pathway by which a signal emits a value and that is passed to a slot.  But it does not execute that.  Look for things like `emit armedChanged(true);` or other connections involving `armedChanged` that might chain the signal from somewhere else (_e.g._ a button "pressed" signal)

Comment: This is actually a 'Qt-specific' issue. You a registering a callback with this function.
`anncounceArmedChanged`  gets called each time, the signal `armedChanged` is triggered. And this call will contain the parameter of whatever is passed to the signal.

Comment: *In this case, where does the program get the armed status?* -- Look at the declaration of `connect`.  That's the piece of the puzzle that's missing from your post, and would probably answer your question immediately.

Answer (score 6):

In this situation, `announceArmedChanged()` is a **callback function**. The code you showed is not *calling* `announceArmedChanged()`. It is passing the *memory address* of `announceArmedChanged` to [`QObject::connect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) of the Qt framework, which will remember the address and associate it with the specified `armedChanged` **event**.  When other code later triggers the `armedChanged` event with an appropriate status value, `announceArmedChanged()` will then be called with that value.

Read [Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) in Qt's documentation for more details.

Comment: Keyword, boldface, italics, keyword link, link....  BINGO! ;)

Answer (score 0):

"armedChanged" is a signal and this siagnal calls "_announceArmedChanged" slot when "emit armedChanged(true);" or "emit armedChanged(false);" Called.
In this case both siganal and slot are in the same class;

Answer (score -2):

> Pointers to member functions
>
> A pointer to non-static member function `f` which is a member of class `C` can be initialized with the expression `&C::f` exactly. Expressions such as `&(C::f)` or `&f` inside `C`'s member function do not form pointers to member functions.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Comment: While technically useful, this really does nothing to answer the OP's question.

Comment: The syntax of the pointer is not asked about. The fact that it is a pointer is part of the answer explanation, but the answer to "Where is  `armed` coming from?" is not given at all.