# C++ header declaration of default values

Tags: c++, function

I am learning C++ and I am using a header file **coffee.hpp** where I declared all functions and a **main.cpp** plus a function declaration file **coffee.cpp**. When using default arguments in this case `bool milk= false` and `bool sugar = false`. So, I wonder why I don't have to declare the default values in the function's declaration file (where I declared the body of the function)? Why it does not cause an error?

Here is the content of my header file:

```
std::string make_coffee(bool milk=false, bool sugar=false);
```

And here is the content of the function's body cpp file:

```
#include <string>

std::string make_coffee(bool milk, bool sugar) {
  std::string coffee = "Here's your coffee";
  if (milk and sugar) {
    coffee += " with milk and sugar";
  } else if (milk) {
    coffee += " with milk";
  } else if (sugar) {
    coffee += " with sugar";
  }
  return coffee + ".\n";
}
```

Comment: [Where to put default parameter value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989483/where-to-put-default-parameter-value-in-c)

Comment: Terminology: that first bit of code is a function **declaration**; the bit in the cpp file is a function **definition**. A function definition can also be a declaration, but that’s not how it’s being used here.

Comment: Default arguments are supplied when the function is *called*, so should generally be specified in the declaration within a header file.   They *can* be supplied in the function definition (since a definition is a type of declaration), as long as all callers have visibility of the definition (e.g. the function is defined inline within a header). Specifying them in both the declaration (in the header) and in the definition is mostly pointless - but can cause confusion (the programmer needs to work out which default values apply) when the caller has visibility of both declaration and definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values are only allowed in *function declarations*, because the compiler has to be able to provide the default values to the function at any call site which doesn't pass in values explicitly.