# How to declare function declaration with default argument value in C++?

Tags: visual-c++

Say, I have the following code which uses `sum` function, which has default value for `skip_value` argument. The `sum` function uses default value:

```cpp
import <print>;
import <vector>;
import <optional>;

std::optional<int> sum(std::vector<int> nums, int skip_value = 100);

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> nums { 10, 20, 30, 100 };
  std::optional<int> result = sum(nums);
  if (result.has_value()) {
    std::println("sum = {}", result.value());
  }
  else {
    std::println("no results were found");
  }
}
std::optional<int> sum(std::vector<int> nums, int skip_value = 100) {
  int result { 0 };
  for (const auto& num : nums) {
    if (num != skip_value)
      result += num;
  }
  if (result == 0) {
    return { };
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}
```

As you can see, function implementation has default value `100` for `skip_value` argument. I write the same in function declaration. However, I get the error:

> Error C2572 'sum': redefinition of default argument: parameter 1

OK. I change function declaration to the following:

```cpp
std::optional<int> sum(std::vector<int> nums, int skip_value);
```

Now I get different error:

> Error C2660 'sum': function does not take 1 arguments

How do I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::optional<int> sum(std::vector<int> nums, int skip_value);` in the definition, the default args go in the declaration.

```cpp
std::optional<int> sum(std::vector<int> nums, int skip_value = 100);

std::optional<int> sum(std::vector<int> nums, int skip_value) {
  int result { 0 };
  for (const auto& num : nums) {
    if (num != skip_value)
      result += num;
  }
  if (result == 0) {
    return { };
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}
```

This should compile.

See also: [Where to put default parameter value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989483/where-to-put-default-parameter-value-in-c)

Comment: I wrote that this does not work when called as `sum(nums)` (i.e. using default argument).

Comment: Ah, you're right. It's the other way around. If you put your default args in the declaration, but not in the definition, that seems to work for me with your code.

Comment: H-m-m-m. This _does_ work, but... is this OK? )) I mean absence of default value in function _implementation_.

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it be? It can only go one place, and the declaration is where it makes the most sense since that's what callers will actually use. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989483/where-to-put-default-parameter-value-in-c

Comment: Change your code, and I will mark it as answer. Happy New Year! 

Comment: Done. Happy new year :)

Comment: Get your +1! ))