# Building fail in Eclipse C/C++ but works well in commandline

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++

[EDIT:]

The problem seems to belong to the functions, that take default-parameters. Without separating in *.h *.cpp and main file it worked as i implemented something like:

```
void foo(double db;);                  // deklaration
void foo(double db = 4){ cout << db;}  // definition
int main(){
    foo();                             // usage
    return 1;
}
```

But if I separate deklaration (-> *.h), definition (-> *.cpp) and usage (-> main) compiling suddenly returns an erro telling, there is no function foo(void), as it does not recognize that there is a default parameter. Any suggestions for that?

[/EDIT]

I wrote a c++-program running somehow like:

```
#include <iostream>
/* other includes */

using namespace std;

class my_class
{
private:
    /* variables */
public:
    /* function deklarations (just some short ones are only defined not declared) */
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, my_class member);

/* Definition of the member functions and of the not-member-function */

int main()
{
    /*some trial codes of member-functions */
    return 1;
}
```

In one total file all compiled well in Eclipse and worked. Now I also wanted to try seperate in a main,class-header and class-cpp file (called them "my_class.h" and my_class.cpp").

For that i put in class-header:

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H_
#define MY_CLASS_H_
#include <iostream>
/* other includes */

using namespace std;

class my_class
{
    /* ... */
};
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, my_class member);
#endif /* MY_CLASS_H_ */
```

I put in class-cpp:

```
/* Definition of the member functions and of the not-member-function */
```

I put in main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_class.h"
#include "my_class.cpp"

int main()
{
    /*some trial codes of member-functions */
    return 1;
}
```

This version is compiling with the g++ command in commandline:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp
```

But it does not Compile in Eclipse. There it gives me the Error:

```
...\my_class.cpp:11.1: error: 'my_class' does not name a type
```

and same for all other member functions and variables. I tried to follow the instructions from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) (I put just "my_class.h" in main and my_class.cpp, but then it did not compile in Eclipse and in command line (of course then with the my_class.cpp included). Eclipse gives me an Error, that makes me believe Eclipse does not see the "my_class.cpp":

```
...\main.cpp:288:47: error: no matching function for call to 'my_class::foo(...)'
```

where foo stands for the first member-function declard in the "my_class.cpp" file. First It gave the error for the constructor too, but as I put it's definition directly into the *.h file it worked well. (That's why I think, it does not see the "my_class.cpp" file)

I think I might be missing something very trivial as I am very new to Eclipse, but I don't see it. I tried to make my questions and information as short as possible.

Comment: Learn how to use a builder like `make` and always pass `-Wall`  (perhaps with `-g`) to `g++`; I believe that you might not need `eclipse` at all for C++ programs (which you could edit with e.g. `emacs`)

Comment: You shouldnot `#include "my_class.cpp"` anywhere.

Comment: @Basile Eclipse automatically uses -Wall -g and thanks for your suggestion, but I'd prefer to try out an IDE for now... up to it was just me and Editor and the compiler

Comment: @ juanchopanza: I know, but - as I said - it is the only way it compiles at the time (at least with g++), that's exactly my problem ;)

Comment: I use CMake and Eclipse. See: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:Eclipse_UNIX_Tutorial

Comment: There should be a possibility in Eclipse CDT to add a new class to project or add existing code to the project. This way Eclipse would create a proper makefile for you. Never include the implementation (C/CPP) files!

Comment: @ Valentin: So you mean including a separate .h and a separate .cpp file (that's what I did) will work different then let them create as a new c++class by the built in function?

Comment: I am not quite sure what to do... shall I now answer my own question or not? On the one hand it will show the answer, it will show the question answered and it is a better syntax, on the other hand my true problem was already solved twice, which from the very beginning I didn't know to be familiar with my problem. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default-parameters need to be declared in the header-file as it contains the declarations and not in the cpp file, which contains the definitions. (An additional mistake was to declare them in the definition). Found some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440222/constructors-with-default-parameters-in-header-files). But why did it work, as I implemented it in one whole file?

[Answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142209/what-if-the-default-parameter-value-is-defined-in-code-not-visible-at-the-call-s)

```
If default-parameter is in the cpp-file, the main file does not see it as
it looks only into the header-file
But if the whole code is included in just one file, the default-value
can be found in the definition too.
```

To explain myself:

I considered answering my question, because it gives a better overview of the whole question and the question will now not appear as unanswered. After reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), I think that it is the right way to do so.